# How to use react-router-dom with Context API V6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I am changing the `value` in `PC` component but it is not reflected in the `BR1` component. If I don't use react-router-dom, everything works fine, but I need the routes.

App.js code

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {  BrowserRouter as Router,   Routes,  Route } from "react-router-dom";
import BR1 from './Components/BR1';
import PC from './Components/P_c1'
import BR from './Components/BR';

export const BRcontext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
    <BRcontext.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/PC' element={<PC/>} />
          <Route path='/BR1' element={<BR1/>} />
          <Route path='/BR' element={<BR/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </BRcontext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PC code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import './Profile.css';
import { BRcontext } from '../App';

export default function Profile() {

    const {value, setValue} = useContext(BRcontext);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container mt-5'>
                <div className='row'>
                    
                    <div>
                       
                        <h3 className='mt-5'>Send Request</h3>
                        <button className='btn btn-success mt-3 ps-3 pe-3' onClick={()=>{setValue(true)}}>Request</button>
                       
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

BR1 code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import BR from './BR'
import { BRcontext } from '../App'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function BR1() {
    const {value} = useContext(BRcontext);
    // let navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
        {console.log(value)} //this remains false
      {value ? <Link to="/BR"/>: console.log('hello there!')}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In BR1 code, I want the `value` to become true when a button in the `PC` component is clicked

Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/great-star-bzhuvw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: *If I don't use react-router-dom, everything works fine* I'm 99% sure you are wrong. This is exactly how I use context in my projects with react-router-dom, never had any issues.

Comment: Can you try to run this same code on your end? Maybe you'll be able to figure out where I'm going wrong

Comment: Are you navigating to `BR1` by typing the URL in the address bar?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/router-context-forked-ci1rwm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, because I don't want to redirect. I just want the change to appear at `BR1` on click

Comment: I don't want a button on the `PC` redirecting to `BR1`. Basically, I want any changes made on `PC` URL to reflect on `BR1` URL

Comment: If you manually change the URL the state is reinitialized (because `<App />` is re-rendered) so it cannot work. You could try to save the state in the `localStorage` and read it from here instead.

Comment: There is nothing wring with the code, per se. The issue is with your approach to testing. When you manually update the URL you are reloading the page and remounting the entire React app, so any local React state is lost. Either persist the state to localStorage or use a navigation action within the app to navigate from the `"/pc"` path to the `"/br1"` path so the React state in the Context is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no way to navigate from /PC to /BR1 unless changing the browser URL directly, and by doing this, you lose the current context value because it's in memory. If you intend to keep this behaviour, you should consider persisting the context value every time you change it and initialize it with the previously persisted one.

An example using the browser's local storage:

```js
// Helper function to read the storaged value if it exists
function getPersistedValue() {
  const serializedValue = localStorage.getItem('value')

  try {
    if (!serializedValue) {
      throw new Error('No previously persisted value found')
    }

    return JSON.parse(serializedValue)
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}

// Using the helper function to initialize the state
const [value, setValue] = useState(getPersistedValue())

// Synchronizing the persisted value on local storage with the in-memory one
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify(value))
}, [value])
```

If you want, I forked your Code Sandbox and applied these changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/router-context-forked-uqhzye.